# set process.env.NODE_ENV in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angular, nestjs, nx-monorepo

I need to set process.env.NODE_ENV to 'production' in local NestJS code. steps i tried-

1. In package.json for the serve script I added NODE_ENV=production
2. in package.json for the build script added nx build --prod.

Even after these settings I get 'development' in process.env.NODE_ENV

looking for a solution to set NODE_ENV to 'production' in local.

I am using Nx monorepo.

Comment: Do you have a .env file on your project ?

Answer (score 1):

NestJS recommends to "create a `ConfigModule` that exposes a `ConfigService` which loads the appropriate .env file".

You can do it via the [@nestjs/config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nestjs/config) npm package which uses [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) under the hood.

It will loads environment variables from a `.env` file in the root directory of the application by default.

Everything is explained in their documentation: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration

Answer (score 0):

You should not set ENV variables in package.json. Use a ".env" to store all your environment variables according to the environment. Don't forget to add the same to your gitignore.

You can use a very famous package for this:

```
npm install dotenv --save
```

Create a .env file in the root of your project

```
NODE_ENV=PRODUCTION
```

```
require('dotenv').config()
console.log(process.env)
```

In ES6

```
import 'dotenv/config'
```